# jQuery widgets disappearing in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two projects I'm working on.  One has a jQuery Datepicker and the other uses the jQuery bxSlider.  I have the same problem with both.  When I navigate to the url where these widgets are located the widgets don't appear.  Only when I hit refresh on my browser do they appear.  Then when I navigate to another link and back again the widgets are gone again until I hit refresh another time.

**EDIT**

I added the following:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  $('.slider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 230,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 10
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having an issue with a new addition to Rails 4 called Turbolinks.  You cannot just bind to the `ready` event because that is only called on a full page reload(which Turbolinks avoids when possible).  You need to bind to `page:change` event like so:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
  $('.slider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 230,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 10
  });
});
```

You can read more about turbo links [here](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).