# Javascript - Display remaining characters of text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have set the `maxlength` of my `textarea` to be 200 and I would like to display a nice countdown function that shows how many characters they have left as they are typing.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <th width="20%" scope="row" valign="top">Description<div id="characters-left"></div></th>
    <td width="80%"><textarea id="text-area" style="width: 48%" name="poll-description" value="" maxlength="200"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

And the JS that I am trying to do it with is like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = textareaLengthCheck();

    function textareaLengthCheck() {
    var textArea = document.getElementById('text-area').value.length;
    var charactersLeft = 200 - textArea;
    var count = document.getElementById('characters-left');
    count.innerHTML = "Characters left: " + charactersLeft;
}
</script>
```

I would rather do this with vanilla javascript as opposed to jQuery if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas about what? What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @Juhana Well it doesn't work. When I type the numbers don't change and if I try `alert(textArea);` in the console, it says can't find variable.

Comment: Shouldn't `textareaLengthCheck()` be on `keypress` or `keyup` of textarea?

Comment: Of course it doesn't find the variable because it's local to the function.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136647/character-countdown-like-on-twitter/2136709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind event listeners for `keyup` and `keydown` like this.

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('text-area');

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', textareaLengthCheck, false);
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', textareaLengthCheck, false);
```

See this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/86dgqaft/).

Or you can do what [Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453095/javascript-display-remaining-characters-of-text-area/34453262#answer-34453257) using HTML5.

Comment: use instead of 'keyup' and 'keydown' the 'input' event, if you Copy&Paste a Text on input or textareas the Event 'keyup' and 'keydown' don't fired! And you need only one eventListener :)

Answer (score 2):

As I have commented, function `textareaLengthCheck` should be a `key` event. Following code depicts same:

```js
function textareaLengthCheck(el) {
  var textArea = el.value.length;
  var charactersLeft = 200 - textArea;
  var count = document.getElementById('lblRemainingCount');
  count.innerHTML = "Characters left: " + charactersLeft;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtInput" onkeypress="textareaLengthCheck(this)"></textarea>
<p id="lblRemainingCount"></p>
```

Comment: the event listnener **onkeypress** will not fire when backspace is clicked, and for that reason the remaining characters will be incorrect if the user deletes wat he has been typing. Replace it with **onkeydown** instead

Answer (score 0):

On jquery, you can do this

```
$('#text-area').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#text-area').text().length < 200) {
        $('#characters-left').text('Characters left: ' + (200 - $('#text-area').text().length));
    }
});
```